# Java: creating int value based on letters alphabetical position

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, int

**My thoughts/Questions:**
I'm working on a Java challenge(Directions bellow).  I have *Part 1* finished(shown in the code bellow).  However, I'm having a hard time making progress with *part 2*.  I'm interested in hearing suggestions/examples as to how I could complete this challenge.  As well as, a possible refactor on my work for Part 1, if needed.

**Challenge Directions:**

Use the names.txt file, a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names found in the resources directory.

*Part 1:* Begin by sorting the list into alphabetical order. Save this new file as p4aNames.txt in the answers directory.

*Part 2:* Using p4aNames.txt, take the alphabetical value for each name, and multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score. For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714. Save the list of all name scores as p4bNames.txt.

*Part 3:* What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

**Pic Link Showing Output & Directory:**

http://screencast.com/t/t7jvhYeN

**My Current Code:**

```js
package app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AlphabetizedList {
 public static void main() throws IOException {
  new AlphabetizedList().sortingList();
 }
 public void sortingList() throws IOException {
  FileReader fb = new FileReader("resources/names.txt");
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fb);
  String out = bf.readLine();
  out = out.substring(out.indexOf("\"")); //get rid of strange characters appearing before firstname 
//  System.out.println(out); Would show unsorted names
  bf.close();
  fb.close();
  
  String[] sortedStr = out.split(",");
  Arrays.sort(sortedStr);
  
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("answers/p4aNames.txt")));
  for (int i = 0; i < sortedStr.length; i++) {
  pw.println(sortedStr[i]);
  System.out.println(sortedStr[i]); // print to console just to see output
  }
  pw.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not really a platform where you can ask other people to completely write your Code. Write your own code and if you're relly stuck, come back, but please show some more effort. What exactly don't you understand for _Part 2_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble figuring out the number value for each character?  Just convert the string to uppercase, cast each character to int, and subtract 64 to get the numeric value for each character.  Something like this:

```
int score = 0;
for (char ch: sortedStr[i].toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
     score += (int)ch - 64;  /* A is decimal 65 */
}
score = score * i; /* multiply by position in the list */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try with resources so that you don't have to explicitly close the file using file.close ..

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("answers/p4bNames.txt")))) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= sortedStr.length; i++) {//starting from1
            int score = 0;
            for (char ch : sortedStr[i-1].toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
                score += ch - 'A' + 1;  //subtracting A for ex if ch is C then C - A will be 2 so adding 1 to make 3
            }
            score *= i;//mutiplying the value by the index
            pw.println(score);
            System.out.println(sortedStr[i]); // print to console just to see output
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```